# how to add comments that are hidden in the rendered quarto revealjs presentation

Tags: reveal.js, quarto

Is there a way to add comments to quarto Revealjs presentation that are hidden from the presentation? Typically in R we use # to comment code so that we can keep track of what we are doing. However if I use # in quarto revealjs document that adds a slider. I am trying to add something that is visible in the code block (to me) but is invisible and doesn't show up in presentation. This is specifically for the "presentation" part of revealjs rather than the code block chuck part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add comments (only visible in the code editor and invisible in the presentation) in the quarto documents and not in the code block (i.e. code-chunk) by using the html syntax  `<!-- some comment -->` for commenting out.

And to add comment hidden in the rendered document, you can use the Quarto extension [`code-visibility`](https://github.com/jjallaire/code-visibility), where you can add `#| hide_line` after each comment to hide that comment in rendered document.

But appending `#| hide_line` after each line seems more typing to me, so I have used the following lua filter `hide-comment.lua` modifying the [source code](https://github.com/jjallaire/code-visibility/blob/main/_extensions/code-visibility/code-visibility.lua) of `code-visibility` veeryy litte and to use it, simply start the comment you want to hide from code chunk with `#>`.

````
---
title: "RevealJS"
format: revealjs
filters:
  - hide-comment.lua
execute: 
  echo: true
---

## Quarto

<!-- This is some hidden comment -->


```{r}
#| message: false
#> This is some hidden comment which is visible in code editor
#> but not in rendered documents
library(dplyr)

#> more hidden comment
mtcars %>% 
  select(mpg, am ,vs) %>% 
  group_by(vs) %>% 
  summarise(mean(mpg))
```
````

**hide-comment.lua**

```
local function filter_lines(text, filter)
  local lines = pandoc.List()
  local code = text .. "\n"
  for line in code:gmatch("([^\r\n]*)[\r\n]") do
    if filter(line) then
      lines:insert(line)
    end
  end
  return table.concat(lines, "\n")
end

function CodeBlock(el)
  if el.classes:includes('cell-code') then
    el.text = filter_lines(el.text, function(line)
      return not line:match("#>")
    end)
    return el
  end
end
```

---

**Update:** I have written a Quarto Extension filter [**`hide-comment`**](https://github.com/shafayetShafee/hide-comment) which can be used to add comments in code chunk that will be hidden in the rendered version of the document.

---

[image: hide comment in quarto]

---

Comment: thanks! I am using alot of fragments, panel-tabsets, .columns, so its helpful to add comments This is so useful, thank you!